# splitting an array sent as a name-value-pair from android to php

Tags: php, android, arrays, json

I am sending arrays of data from an android app to a php server using json (JSON array placed in JSON object)and httppost.It arrives in the format:

```
stdClass Object
(
[records] => [{"total":"149500.0","product":"Sample","id":"0","qty":"23","invoice":"2.5082015020603E13"},{"total":"129600.0","product":"Shell - Large Plastic","id":"0","qty":"36","invoice":"2.5082015020603E13"}]
)
```

PHP CODE:

```
if ($_POST) {
    echo "Smething was sent";

    $JSON_Entry = $_POST["Entry"];

    $obj = json_decode($JSON_Entry);

    foreach ($obj as $key => $value) {
        echo $value[0];
    }
}
```

My problem is if I use the for each in the code above, it brings the '['. How can I split them so as to store in a database or variables?

Comment: try `echo $value[$key];` instead `echo $value[0];`

Comment: it displays the opening '['. Could it be an issue with the JSON syntax?

Comment: `[<your data>]` means that your json is inside a one level numerically indexed array, so you can access it by, `$array[0]` after `json_decode`. but show how you are sending the json to server, could be an issue there.